# No implementation found for method camera#animate on channel Flutter

Tags: google-maps, flutter

No implementation found for method camera#animate on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_maps_1 and
plugins.flutter.io/google_maps_0 in flutter

I'm reviewing a project in flutter integrating google maps with firebase, when loading the map everything works fine, although a little slow but when closing the activity I get the errors mentioned above. Besides that the device gets very hot, is this normal?

Comment: Please ensure that the methods you are using match that version of the package.... If it persists share the snippet of code you are using.

Comment: Thanks, it worked very well updating google maps, if I have any other errors I will write here

Answer (score 1):

"No implementation found for method" errors from plugins used are usually caused by either outdated plugin versions or the downloaded plugin not building properly. Running `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get` should help generate build files again. If that doesn't work, you can try updating the plugin's version.